# How large should a type be to pass by reference rather than by value?

Tags: c++

Considering move semantics as well, is there a sort of cutoff that defines when it's more expensive to pass by reference rather than by value?

I always see examples use fundamental types by value and some example `class` by reference. But if I have a small `struct` or a small `class`, is it better to pass these by value rather than reference?

Where's the cutoff?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Pass basic built in types by value, user defined types by reference. Mind though that every rule has at least one exception.

Comment: roughly the pointer size * 2

Comment: It's always bugged me that in modern C++ this micro-optimization still has to be done by hand (and what's more, a good understanding of move semantics is required to know when to pass larger types by value)

Comment: Don't just think in terms of size. Think in terms of difficulty to copy. `std::vector`'s not all that big. The stuff in vector might be damn nasty, which brings us back to @101010 's rule of thumb.

Comment: Yeah but on a 32bit machine, a pointer is 4 bytes, a `int` is at least 2 bytes. So, a class that's just 2 `int`s, let's say `coord`, should I continue to pass by value?

Comment: Pass it by reference 'cause if you make add stuff to it later on, you won't have to change every instance of it to be passed by reference

Comment: @MattMcNabb Completely agree. But it seems (correct me if I'm wrong), that due to the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), a compiler is allowed to pass parameters the way it wants, if the behavior does not change.

Comment: @AlexD it is; but that's a tough challenge for the compiler if the function body is in a different unit (or in a library). Also it is tough for the compiler to perform an assessment of which will be faster.

Comment: @AlexYan let's just assume that in the case of my `coord` class, I'm never going to add anything.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: for a simple logic, you can use a template. I know, boiler-plate code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pass by reference is basically a pass by pointer (in terms of efficiency).

A pass by pointer/reference is moving one machine-native length piece of data (aka: one word, or 32-bits on a 32-bit machine, etc...)

So passing by value any sized data less than or equal to a native word will be as efficient as passing by pointer/reference.

If your data/object is larger than this, it will take multiple cycles to copy each word of that to the stack.

There are no efficiencies gained by passing by value when the data size is less than a word. The machine will execute a copy which takes just as long for half a word as it does a full word.

Comment: Is there a way to factor in the padding that the compiler can add to data members for alignment? Other than just using `sizeof` at some point? And, considering that a value less than a word takes as long as a reference, why does anyone ever pass built-in types by value?

Comment: Pass by reference wasn't always around. Straight C and very old versions of C++ only had pass by value or by pointer. Pass by reference came about as a safer way to, essentially, pass by pointer.

So you might ask, why use pass by value if you can just pass by pointer all the time? All of the usual answers apply here. 

One other reason to pass by value over reference is there might be a speed optimization on some low end hardware platforms. Passing by reference still requires an address lookup to get the data. Pass by value puts the data right on the stack.

Comment: @NeomerArcana to answer your other question about padding: You can pack your structs/classes to get the most efficient use of space when you pass objects around (see your compilers pragma pack). This will usually have the effect of screwing up the alignment of the data members. So if you have a class with a unit32, a uint16 and a uint64, normally there would be 4 bytes of pad after the 32, 6 bytes of pad after the 16 and the 64 would be at the end (assuming a 64bit architecture) if you pack the class, there is no padding. The only way to know for sure how big the object is is to use sizeof.

Comment: This answer is not correct - for sure the passing itself won't make a difference, but passing by pointer / reference adds inefficiencies as soon as you use the passed pointer / reference in the function. Example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qrGh5Yd99 ; the compiler will reload from memory / cache on every access to x instead of just using the value in a register